# How can I make the Gtk.TextView render correctly in a Gtk.Box without requiring the user to resize the window first?

Tags: gtk, gnome

Whenever I have a `Gtk.Box` with a `Gtk.TextView` inside, the text view is not displayed correctly until I resize the window.

Here are screenshots of an example:

- [Before resizing window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDf1i.png)
- [After resizing window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fWge.png)

Let me show you a minimal reproducible example with a `Gtk.Box` containing a `Gtk.TextView` directly as the child of a window (UI description in Blueprint):

```
template $ExampleWindow : Adw.ApplicationWindow {
    Box {
        orientation: vertical;
        TextView { }
    }
}
```

When I open the window, no text view is visible. It appears after changing the window size.

#### Update

[Kripto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4409163/kripto) suggested in his answer to set the `vexpand` of the `Gtk.TextView` to `true`. That solves the problem, but I want the text view to stay as small as possible (e.g. one line for one or no line of text, two lines for two lines of text, three for three, etc.), and not to expand vertically. After resizing the window manually, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kripto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4409163/kripto) just wrote a comment which answers my question:

> What resolved it for me was adding a height-request to Gtk.TexView, after which it started displaying normally.

I changed the minimal reproducible example in Blueprint to this:

```
template $ExampleWindow : Adw.ApplicationWindow {
    Box {
        orientation: vertical;
        TextView {
            height-request: 20;
        }
    }
}
```

The text view now appears with the specified height and then expands when I add lines to the text in the text view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the widget changing when resizing the window, but if you want the **Gtk.TextView** to expand horizontally and vertically you have to add **vexpand** and **hexpand**.

Here's an example in BluePrint:

```
using Gtk 4.0;
using Adw 1;

template $ExampleWindow: Adw.ApplicationWindow {

default-width:600;
default-height:400;
    
    Box {
        orientation: vertical;
        
        Adw.HeaderBar{}
        
       
        
        TextView { 
        vexpand:true;
        hexpand:true;
        margin-top:30;
        margin-end:30;
        margin-start:30;
        
        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. I don't actually wanted the text view to expand vertically (with the `vexpand` property set to `true`, the problem I'm facing does not occur). The only thing I have to change in your code so that the problem occurs is commenting out the line with `vexpand`. Thanks for the answer, I'm gonna update the question based on that information!

Comment: Strange, here, if I remove the vexpand, the TextView assumes the default behavior which is to start with the height of one line, no resizing changes this. There must be another element causing this problem, what version of GTK are you using?

Comment: I'm using GTK version 4.0, running in the `org.gnome.Sdk` runtime version `master` (does also happen with `44`).

Comment: Funny, I just faced the same problem here in a totally different situation. Apparently it only happens with text widgets. What resolved it for me was adding a height-request to Gtk.TexView, after which it started displaying normally.

Comment: Thank you very much for this comment, @Kripto, it solves the problem!